# Make href to PDF open in new tab in Firefox/IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

EDIT: I found the answer -- see comment below

I'm writing a landing page with button to a pdf that is supposed to open in a new tab. Using `<a target='_blank' href='link_to_pdf.pdf'>` works perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox and IE, clicking the button does absolutely nothing.

I've tried looking in docs, but I just find user's saying they can't open them, not developers..

Comment: I found that it works if i wrap the link around the button instead of the other way around. I have no idea why though.